# Single sign-on to OneDrive for business using Integrated Windows Authentication

Tags: .net, azure-active-directory, onedrive, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to authenticate to OneDrive for business account using Integrated Windows Authentication as mentioned in [Integrated Windows Authentication - AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet Wiki](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Integrated-Windows-Authentication#constraints).

It is a Windows desktop application and On-premise AD is synced to Azure AD using 'AD Connect'. I am getting `MsalClientException` from API `AcquireTokenByIntegratedWindowsAuthAsync()`. Is it a supported workflow to authenticate OneDrive for business from Windows desktop apps?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: I am getting MsalClientException. Will Integrated Windows Authentication work for OneDrive For Business ?

Comment: MsalClientException is the type of exception :) But what is the Message in the exception?